# How to Access AWS EC2 Windows Instance Via Web Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Am new to AWS-EC2.  Have a Windows EXE running on EC2 Instance and can access it via Windows Remote Desktop.

How, if possible, do I configure AWS-EC2 instance to be accessed from a web browser rather than Windows Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the Remote Desktop Web Client.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-web-client

I'm assuming you're looking for remote machine access similar to Remote Desktop with a web browser as opposed to setting it up as a web server.

Comment: Bill: I've read that article and have no idea as to where to find the URL of my AWS Ec2 Insance - I am only able to get there via Windows Remote Desktop - . I need someone to walk me through the process - can you assist??
Lee

Answer (score -2):

if Microsoft html5 client performance is not good enough, check this other solution.

https://www.cybelesoft.com/blog/windows-remote-desktop-internet-web-rdp/